# Variable assignment and usage in the same expression

Tags: c++

I encountered a line of code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 40;
a = a + b - (b = a);
cout << a << "   " << b << endl;
```

I cannot understand what happens in this code.
Can anyone explain for me?

Comment: Someone removed spaces in expressions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). the value of `b` is changed ***and*** used for computation without an intervening sequence point. The results of the program are unpredictable - it can print anything or crash, or do do some nasty system calls.

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order
>   in which side effects take place, is unspecified.53) Between the
>   previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored
>   value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored. The requirements of this paragraph shall be met
>   for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full
>   expression; otherwise the behavior is ***undefined***.

Comment: @Zhao: When the behavior is undefined, you can't say ***anything*** about the behavior of the program. Anything at all.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan Great answer. Thanks for enlightening. +1

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 0):

This is **undefined behavior** because vairable b has been modified then used in the same expression so the **final result is ambiguous** because it depends on the order of the expression evalution. 
The `(b=a)` could happen before or after b vairable being used to calcualte `a+b`.